# Why is AWS S3 Redirect Showing as 302 instead of 301?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, 301-redirect

I'm implementing a 301 redirect in S3 using this blog post from when [the functionality was first announced](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-support-for-website-redirects/).

It explicitly says the redirect will be a 301, which is what I want.

Screenshot of the meta data:

[image]

The redirect is from: 
http://www.trevormckendrick.com/legal-entity 
to 
http://www.zerotoentrepreneur.com/basic-legal-entity-info-start-here/

But when I curl the 1st url it comes up as 302.

Also, Moz shows two separate redirects, one for
"http://www.trevormckendrick.com/legal-entity"

and another for
"http://www.trevormckendrick.com/legal-entity/"

(note the trailing "/" at the end of the string).

What am I missing?

(Not sure if this would affect it, but I just moved the site from Github Pages to AWS last night.)

[image]

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=592609

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed in the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html)

The 301 redirect is working; however, it redirects to the page with a leading slash before serving the 301 redirect to the configured sites